# Problem with loops in python dictionaries

Tags: python

I am new to python so maybe my problem is easy to solve.

I am having a hard time understanding the dictionaries and how to get only the number(integer) out that I want to compare with.
I have googled for 8 hours and my head hurts a bit.

The error I get: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Here is my code:

```
dictionary1 = {
  "name": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "price": [55, 100, 25]
}

highest_price = 0
winner = ""

for value in dictionary1:
    bid_amount = dictionary1["price"]
    if bid_amount > highest_price:
        highest_price = bid_amount
        winner = name1[name]

print(f"the winner is: {winner}. With {highest_price}")
```

Comment: the `bid_amount` in your loop is a list not an element of a list. That's why you have iterated on the keys of your dictionary, not the elements of `dictionary1["price"]`

Answer (score 3):

#### Technical problem

This first line in your `for` loop doesn't return one price as an integer but the whole price list. This `dictionary1["price"]` gives you `[55, 100, 25]`.

#### Logical problem

##### Data structure

I think you misunderstood how a dictionary work. In your case it seems the best to use a dictionary with a structure where the prices are the values and the names are the keys.

```
better_dict = {
    'a': 55,
    'b': 100,
    'c': 25}
```

In the solution code below I transform your dict via `dict(zip(...))` into that form.

##### Iterate over a dictionary

When you iterate over a dictionary with a `for` loop you only get the keys not the values. In my example you have the keys `['a', 'b', 'c']`. When you want to access the values in a dictionary you have to use the key inside the loop.

#### Solution

This solutions tries to modify your code as less as possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
dictionary1 = {
  "name": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "price": [55, 100, 25]
}

# transform your dict into an easier structure
better_dict = dict(zip(dictionary1["name"], dictionary1["price"]))
# result --> {'a': 55, 'b': 100, 'c': 25}

highest_price = 0
winner = ""

for name in better_dict:  # --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
    # get the value by key/name
    bid_amount = better_dict[name]
    if bid_amount > highest_price:
        highest_price = bid_amount
        winner = name  # use the key as name

print(f"the winner is: {winner}. With {highest_price}")
```

#### Alternative solution

Here you have an alternative approach without using a `for` loop. It also uses the transformed data structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
dictionary1 = {
  "name": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "price": [55, 100, 25]
}

better_dict = dict(zip(dictionary1["name"], dictionary1["price"]))
# result --> {'a': 55, 'b': 100, 'c': 25}

# Find key with highest price
winner = sorted(better_dict, key=lambda k: better_dict[k])[-1]
# Get highest price by winners name
highest_price = better_dict[winner]

print(f"the winner is: {winner}. With {highest_price}")
```

I will try to break down the `winner =` line for you. `sorted(better_dict)` (without `key=`!) would return the keys (names) of the dictionary. But you want the values. So `key=lambda k: better_dict[k]` tell the `sorted()` to use the `lambda` function that returns the value of an element indexed by a key `k`. Because `sorted()` use ascending (lowest to highest price) order by default we use the last element of the returned list to get the name with the highest price. You can access the last element of a list via `[-1]`.

Comment: Ok. Now it finnaly makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Inline:

```
dictionary1["name"][dictionary1["price"].index(max(dictionary1["price"]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would rearrange the structure of your dict, so that the letters a, b, c are the keys and the numbers are the values

   ```
   dictionary1 = {
        "a": 55,
        "b": 100,
        "c": 25
    }
   ```
2. You can sort the dictionary by value and reverse the sorting order so that the entry with the highest key is at the first position. This can be done by using the `sorted` function. There you have to set the `key` argument on `dictionary1.get` to sort by value and also set the `reverse` parameter on true. Finally you have to access the first element and the key with the highest value will be returned.

   `sorted(dictionary1, key=dictionary1.get, reverse=True)[0]`

Here ist the complete code:

```
dictionary1 = {
    "a": 55,
    "b": 100,
    "c": 25
}
max_entry = sorted(dictionary1, key=dictionary1.get, reverse=True)[0]

print(f"the winner is: {max_entry}. With {dictionary1[max_entry]}")
```

And the reason why you get this error is, because you try to compare the whole list "price" with the variable highest_price

Comment: As @buhtz did it, you could also skip the reversed parameter and access the `[-1]` element (which is the last). This might be a bit smarter.